# a function call changes it's parameters

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Iterator;

template <class T>
class List;

template <class T>
class List {
    public:
        struct Node;
        Node* first;
        friend class Iterator<T>;

        List() :
            first(NULL) { }

        Iterator<T> begin() {
            cout << first->data << endl;
            return Iterator<T>(*this, first); // <--- problematic call
        }

        void insert(const T& data) {
            Node newNode(data, NULL);
            first = &newNode;
        }
};

template <class T>
struct List<T>::Node {
    private:
        T data;
        Node* next;

        friend class List<T>;
        friend class Iterator<T>;

        Node(const T& data, Node* next) :
            data(data), next(next) { }
};

template <class T>
class Iterator {
    private:
        const List<T>* list;
        typename List<T>::Node* node;

        friend class List<T>;

    public:
        Iterator(const List<T>& list, typename List<T>::Node* node) {
            cout << node->data << endl;
        }
};

int main() {
    List<int> list;
    list.insert(1);
    list.begin();

    return 0;
}
```

First I set the node data to "1" (int). Ater that I just pass it to the `Iterator` constructor, but it changes the value of `node->data`.

I printed `node->data` before and after the call:

```
1
2293232
```

I guess that `2293232` is an address of something, but I can't find the reason this happens.

Comment: A much better worded question than the last attempt. Good job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write

```
    void insert(const T& data) {
        Node newNode(data, NULL);
        first = &newNode;
    }
```

Then:

1. You create an object on the stack
2. Point some (more) persistent pointer to its address
3. Destruct it as it goes out of scope

So you're left with garbage stuff.